# How mapping with .map a .json file using translation with i18next in React.js?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, jsx, array.prototype.map

Hello guys i have a question for you. Actually i want to map and render a component using text from a .json and using translation based on user language or detected language.

That's the translation.json (the same for another language)

```
{ "myText":[
          { "id":1,
            "text":"my text"
          },
          {
            "id":2,
            "text":"my text"
          }
  ]
}
```

Now i want to map this .json and return the text based on language in my component. If i do:

```js
import { withNamespaces } from 'react-i18next';
import data from '../locales/en/translation.json';

function Component({t}) {
  return (
    <>
      {data.myText.map((item) => (
        <div key={t(item.id)}>
          {t(item.text)}
        <div/>       
    ))}          
    </>
  )
}

export default withNamespaces()(Component)
```

That's return only the "en" translation because the import is based on this .json file. Now how to have the translation based on user language through .map ?

Comment: Can you put that in a sandbox?

Comment: You may want to checkout the official example of react-i18next: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react

Answer (score 1):

Ok i did it using:

```
{i18next.t('myText', { returnObjects: true }).map((item) => (
    <div key={t(item.id)}>
      {t(item.text)}
    </div>
))}
```

Solution is here: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays#arrays